# The Bauschinger effect

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials

I have a question on the Bauschinger effect. Let's say that we have a material with yield stress $400 \,\mathrm{MPa}$, and let's say that the actual applied stress is tensile for starters. If we load the material to the point where the stress is, for example, $500 \,\mathrm{MPa}$, then that means that the loading has surpassed the material's yield stress by $100 \,\mathrm{MPa}$ and that the material has entered the inelastic region.

If the direction of stress is now reversed, from tensile to compressive, the Bauschinger effect tells us that the new compressive yield stress will be lower than the initial one and will be $-400+100=-300 \,\mathrm{MPa}$.

What I want to know is: What happens if in my initial loading of the material I don't surpass the yield strength? In other words, if yielding occurs at $400 \,\mathrm{MPa}$, I apply less than that ($350 \,\mathrm{MPa}$, for example). If I now unload and start loading with compressive stress, does the Bauschinger effect apply? Or is the yield stress for compressive loading still $-400 \,\mathrm{MPa}$?

Thanks in advance.
Note: I don't know what tags to add, so if you know of more suitable ones, please add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bauschinger effect is based on plastic strain , so there would be no effect for stresses in the elastic strain ranges. I learned this from Drs N.H.Polakowski and S  Mostovoy before there were computers so no tags. However; I am sure they have references in the literature.

Comment: Thank you. I guessed that there must be no effect if we are in the elastic range but I wanted to make sure of it!